# Ubuntu Can't turn on, only flashed the logo

Tags: kernel, ubuntu-core, error-handling

I have problems with my Ubuntu for sometime, but everytime I managed to fix it through recovery mode, this time it is different, because it is stuck on the flashing logo with some fails that show up. I managed to take a picture of it. Please help I need my PC asap.

This is the photo of the flashing ubuntu screen

[Photo of the startup screen](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LofPl1uH-Yxmv3fgmbQmSi6lQkGeXCVS/view?usp=drivesdk)

And this is recovery mode photo

[Linux Recovery Mode](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LoSdM9rwoPlBQ7XmCRqYhb1eN70xkWCO/view?usp=drivesdk)

Comment: Maybe you could tell us which release number of Ubuntu is in use? 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: You've tagged it's a IoT (Ubuntu Core) release, but photos look like a laptop where usually desktop releases are installed.  Again please provide specifics of release.

Comment: Sorry about that, it is Ubuntu 18.04 64-Bit